# Write depth buffer to texture

Tags: c++, rendering, directx10

I need to read depth buffer from GPU and write it to texture. How this can be done?
Here is how texture for depth buffer is created:

```
depthBufferDesc.Width = screenWidth;
depthBufferDesc.Height = screenHeight;
depthBufferDesc.MipLevels = 1;
depthBufferDesc.ArraySize = 1;
depthBufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;
depthBufferDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
depthBufferDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
depthBufferDesc.Usage = D3D10_USAGE_DEFAULT;
depthBufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D10_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL;
depthBufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
depthBufferDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

m_device->CreateTexture2D(&depthBufferDesc, NULL, m_depthStencilBuffer);
```

Also, I've got another question: is it possible to bind depth buffer texture as sampler to the pixel shader?

Answer (score 1):

You bind that texture to a depth stencil view and also a shader resource view to sample from it in another shader.

You need to add D3D10_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE to the depthBufferDesc.BindFlags field.

Comment: I have following settings for stencil depthStencilViewDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT; and this how I try to obtain resource  `D3D10_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC srDesc;
srDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32_FLOAT;
srDesc.ViewDimension = D3D10_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
srDesc.Texture2D.MostDetailedMip = 0;
srDesc.Texture2D.MipLevels = 1;`

ID3D10ShaderResourceView* Resource;
m_device->CreateShaderResourceView( m_depthStencilBuffer, &srDesc, &Resource );

Comment: You need to make sure that your formats match up - in this case use DXGI_FORMAT_R24G8_TYPELESS for the SRV desc.